# How to map my numpy array to my dataframe index

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, mapping

I am trying to map an array of weights to a group of tickers, but for some reason it is not working. There is no error it is just that the weights do not correspond to the tickers:

```
tickers_list=['GOOG','TSLA','AMZN','CP']
shares_owned=[100,700,200,50]

total_shares =sum(shares_owned)
##-- TIME PERIOD --##
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
start="2000-01-01"
end="2023-01-01"

#convert date to string
import datetime
format_str = '%Y-%m-%d'
datetime_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, format_str)
datetime_end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, format_str)

#DIFFERNCE BETWEEN START AND END DATES IN DAYS---
date_diff=(datetime_end-datetime_start)
date_diff_days=date_diff.days

data = yf.download(tickers_list, start, end)['Adj Close']
spy_ind=yf.download('^GSPC', start, end)['Adj Close'] # INDEX 

weights =np.random.random(len(tickers_list))
weights /=np.sum(weights)
returns=(data/data.shift(1))-1
returns_index=(spy_ind/spy_ind.shift(1)) -1
weighted_returns=[]
weighted_returns=shares_owned*returns

weighted_returns['PORT_RETURN'] = weighted_returns.sum(axis=1)/total_shares
Cumulative_ret = (returns+1).cumprod()
Cumulative_index = (returns_index+1).cumprod()
Cumulative_port_ret = (weighted_returns['PORT_RETURN']+1).cumprod()

mean_daily_ret=returns.mean()
mean_return_ann=(((returns.mean()*252)+1))-1 #annualize daily returns 
#mean_returns_dict = dict(zip(tickers_list, mean_return_ann))

std_dev=np.std(returns)
import math


#-----------MONTE CARLO SIMULATION---------------
  for i in range (10):
    
    weights =np.random.random(len(tickers_list))
    weights /=np.sum(weights)
    preturns.append(np.sum(mean_return_ann*weights))
    print(mean_return_ann)
    print(weights)
    pvariances.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(returns.cov(),weights))))
    pweights.append(weights)
      
  preturns =np.array(preturns)
  print("portfolio returns-------")
  print(preturns)
  max_ret = np.where(preturns == preturns.max())
  #print(max_ret)
  maxReturn = np.amax(preturns)
  #print(maxReturn)

  #portfolio variance = w12σ12 + w22σ22 + 2w1w2Cov1,2

  print("portfolio variances------")
  pvariances =np.array(pvariances)
  print(pvariances)

  pweights =np.array(pweights)
```

Here is a sample of the output, below are the tickers and their corresponding returns and weights . The group below shows the group with the optimal weights out of 10 simulations. How can I get the weights (2nd col of DF) to properly map to the tickers, ive tried everything including join, concat??

AMZN    0.253906
CP      0.217467
GOOG    0.241529
TSLA    0.510510
weights:
**[**0.19824483 0.29516273 0.23614463 0.27044782]****

```
 RETURN            OPT_WT    STD DEV  SHARPE RATIO  SHARES_OWNED  SHARES_OPT  \
```

GOOG  0.241529  **0.198245**  30.750919     12.468428           100        20.0
TSLA  0.510510  **0.295163**  57.124065     14.186836           700       207.0
AMZN  0.253906  **0.23614463** 50.651217      7.957614           200        47.0
CP    0.217467  **0.270448**  30.531963     11.306763            50        14.0